# Speaker Walkaround

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, digital

Does anyone know what Speaker Walkaround means in context of a digital amplifier?
Also how is this test performed?

Lastly, how is it different from Load Diagnostics in Amplifiers?

Comment: Hi! Never heard of it, but you should definitively tell us in which context you've seen that term - link to a source if possible!

Comment: The only context I've known "speaker walk-around" to be used is in multi-channel setups. The test would involve playing a little bit of pink noise through each speaker in turn to make sure that A. each speaker is hooked correctly and B. the quality of audio was consistent across channels. Without a reference, it would be tricky to say for definite this is what your digital amplifier documentation is describing.